# Checking between two radio buttons with javascript .prop('checked');

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have these two radio buttons and I am checking to see if one of them is checked with the below javascript. As I type this question I realize that my script only checks if a specific radio button is checked. How can I check to verify that one of the two are checked?

```js
jQuery(".GenderM1").each(function() {
  var isChecked = jQuery(this).prop('checked');
  if (isChecked == false) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pass = "false";
    alert("Please select gender.");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<td>
  <input type="radio" name="persinfo_gender[0]" <?php if($row_c->persinfo_gender == "0") echo "checked";?> id="maleradio" class="GenderM1" value="0" required>M
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="persinfo_gender[0]" <?php if($row_c->persinfo_gender == "1") echo "checked";?> id="female_redio" class="GenderM1" value="1" required>F
</td>
```

Comment: `if ($('.GenderM1:checked').length == 1)`

Comment: Or just `if ($('.GenderM1:checked').length)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code**

```
jQuery(".GenderM1").each(function() {
  var isChecked = jQuery(this).prop('checked');
  if (isChecked == false) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pass = "false";
    alert("Please select gender.");
    return false;
  }
});
```

You're comparing a boolean variable against a boolean value, use it directly:

```
isChecked == false// Use !isChecked
          ^
```

You're using an undeclared `e`, probably you thin that `.each` receives an event.

```
e.preventDefault();
^
```

The main problem is your loop comparing each radiobutton.checked attribute, you need to check is at least one of then is checked to stop your loop.

**This code snippet show how to check if a radiobutton was checked:**

```js
var isChecked = false;
jQuery(".GenderM1").each(function() {
  isChecked = isChecked || jQuery(this).is(':checked');
  if (isChecked)
    return false;
});

if (!isChecked) {
  var pass = "false";
  alert("Please select gender.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="persinfo_gender[0]" class="GenderM1" value="0" required>M
<br>
<input type="radio" name="persinfo_gender[0]" checked class="GenderM1" value="1" required>F
```

See?, the alert is not being shown when a radiobutton is checked.

**Now, the best approach to know whether a radiobutton group has at least one of them checked:**

```
$('.GenderM1:checked').length
```

The line above returns how many radiobuttons are checked (1 or 0) because you only can select one of then.  That selector works with checkboxes as well.

Answer (score -2):

the method .prop() is available since jQuery 1.6, in previous versions you have to use the method .attr()

which version do you use?

Still I think that what you want to do is that if you have not selected a genre that shows an error and with the code you have, it will not work well. To do this you must do the following:

1- Mark one of them selected by default, that is, establish it as checked by default, this eliminates the possibility that the error of not marking it will be committed.
2- Modify the validation you perform, otherwise it will always return false because only one will be selected and you will go through the entire radiobuttons arrangement, so that when you reach the unselected radiobuttons it will return false.

```
    if ($('input[class="GenderM1"]').is(':checked')) {
        // do something;
    } else {
        //do another thing;
    }
```